# Lamar register service with interface having multiple parameters

Tags: c#, .net-core, inversion-of-control, lamar

Brief Intro - we are using Lamar as IoC container.

I am looking for some help to understand how to register a service which implements interfaces with multiple parameters.
my interface =>

```
interface IEntityCompareService<G, in T1, in T2> { IList<G> Compare(T1 previous, T2 current); }
```

and my implementation goes like this,

```
class ComparisonService : IEntityChangeCompareService<Template G, model A, model B>
```

I am not able to find any way to register this service. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to my question from another source. Adding it here so it might be helpful to others facing similar issue,

```
For<IEntityChangeCompareService<Template, TypeA, TypeB>().Use<ComparisonService>()
```

I tested this in my code, and it works well.